# PHP redirect only root domain

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

i need a php code redirect only my index page to another site very fast 
somthing like this but the problem is : this code redirect all page

```
 <?php    
  header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);      
  header( 'Location: http://www.fastfreesurfing.cf/' ) ;      
  exit();      
?>
```

Comment: Place it only in your index page, so it will redirect only in the index page.

Comment: whats wrong with htaccess? if you need it to be "very fast"?

Comment: if Htaccess work with google app engine

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '/index.php') {
    header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);      
    header( 'Location: http://www.fastfreesurfing.cf/' ) ;      
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Not Working Friend :p

Comment: Do: echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER); echo '</pre>'; and postthe response.

Comment: same the first code is working now :) tnahk you for all